# Dropcaps in word, how to remove the margin/line spacing

Tags: microsoft-word

I am attempting to make headings with dropcaps.  Everything works, except I am unable to get the line spacing/margin of the dropcap to line up with the top of the first line.   Is there anyway to set negative line spacing? Or margin 0?

[image]